# recoger y uso parámetro de entrada por URL con Django y Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, sql, djangorestframework

Django Rest_framework, necesito que haga una consulta en la BD dinámica, necesito que sea por **refcat** dado por el usuario a través de la url, no es pk. Por primari key que es id no tengo problemas.

Esta consulta:

```
`(queryset = Predio.objects.filter(refcat__startswith='080010101000003').order_by('refcat'))`
```

La numeracion **refcat** la ha de dar el usuario y no siempre completa,  nosotros recogemos el parámetro para utilizarlo en la consulta (Ahora mismo lo hace, pero ERROR) :

```
FieldError at /predios/api/predio/
Cannot resolve keyword 'predio' into field. Choices are:).
```

La gracia es que sea dinámica y según pida el usuario saldrá un refcat u otro.

este es el link que utilizo:

```
http://prediales.local/apps/prediales_proves/predios/api/predio/?refcat=080010003000000000258000000000
```

**serializers.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Predio


class PredioSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Predio
        fields = ('refcat', 'id', 'destino')
        lookup_field= 'refcat'
```

**api.py** (vistas)

```
from .models import Predio
from .serializers import PredioSerializer
from rest_framework import viewsets

class PredioViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
serializer_class = PredioSerializer
#filter_fields = {'refcat': [startswith]}

def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):

    refcat = self.kwargs['refcat']
    return Predio.objects.filter(predios__refcat=kwargs)
```

***urls.py***

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from rest_framework import routers
from .api import PredioViewSet

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'predio', PredioViewSet, base_name='predio')

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api/(?P<refcat>.+)/$', PredioViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'})),
]
```

Donde se encuentra el Error, ya me volví loco cambiando de todo y... Error!!
De manera estática, como comento arriba no hay problema, no quiero usar filtros backend a ser posible, ja que no gestiono la app yo, solo la API.
Gracias!

He cambiado cosas y ahora parece que la hace, pero me sale lista vacía, alguna idea? 
Aquí esta como lo que he cambiado (serializers.py continua igual):

apy.py (views.py)

```
from .models import Predio
from .serializers import PredioSerializer
from rest_framework import viewsets
from django.db.models import Q


class PredioViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    lookup_field = 'refcat'

    # filter(refcat__startswith=kwargs.refcat)

    #    refcat__startswith='080010101000003').order_by('refcat')
    serializer_class = PredioSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        Q = Predio.objects.all()
        return Q.filter(refcat__startswith=self.kwargs)
```

urls.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from rest_framework import routers
from .api import PredioViewSet

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'predio', PredioViewSet, base_name='predio')

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls))
]
```

El resultado mediante el es:
link:http://prediales.local/apps/prediales_proves/predios/api/predio/?
refcat=080

o 
http://prediales.local/apps/prediales_proves/predios/api/predio/?refcat=080010003000000000258000000000

[]

vacio en los 2 casos, y es imposible ya que si hay datos en la bd con esa numeración.

Sin embargo si hago esto en api.py (views.py) de manera estatica:

```
from .models import Predio
from .serializers import PredioSerializer
from rest_framework import viewsets


class PredioViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Predio.objects.filter(
        refcat__startswith='080010101000003').order_by('refcat')
    serializer_class = PredioSerializer
```

me devuelve una lista como la que necesito:
[{"destino":"P","refcat":"080010101000003000001000000000","id":7293},{"destino":"C","refcat":"080010101000003010002000000000","id":21480},{"destino":"A","refcat":"080010101000003010004000000000","id":1201},{"destino":"A","refcat":"080010101000003010005000000000","id":40334},{"destino":"A","refcat":"080010101000003010006000000000","id":3200},{"destino":"A","refcat":"080010101000003010007000000000","id":29369}, etc...

Así que creo que el error que no se encontrar esta en la URL y la forma de cazar/utilizar el parámetro, ¿alguna ayuda/idea?

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED
Me ayudo un compañero y ya encontramos la solución:

SERIALIZERS.PY

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models.predio import Predio


class PredioSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Predio
        fields = ('refcat', 'id', 'destino')
```

API.PY(VISTAS)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models.predio import Predio
from .serializers import PredioSerializer
from rest_framework import generics, viewsets


class PredioList(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Predio.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PredioSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        refcat = self.request.query_params.get('refcat')
        return Predio.objects.filter(refcat__startswith=refcat)
```

urls.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from rest_framework import routers
from .api import PredioList

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'predio', PredioList, base_name='predio')

urlpatterns = [
    # include(router.urls))
    url(r'^api/(?P<refcat>.+)/$', PredioList.as_view({'get': 'list'}))
]
```

¿Como accedo?
    **por refcat (completo o incompleto) són 32 números, podemos poner incluso sólo 1 de ellos(pero a menos números la bd más trabajará) **

```
http://prediales.local/apps/prediales_proves/predios/api/predio/?refcat=08001010100000332000
```

Comment: Me alegra que encontraras la solucion. Pero intenta mejorar la respuesta con más explicacion de qué tenias mal o cómo la respuesta funciona para asi ser de utilidad para futuros usuarios. Mira [answer] para más info. Un saludo